# How to customize uipickerview appearence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

i want to customize my UIPickerview appearence, like change font etc.
how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement vie for row delegate method of uipicker view.
Create a  label ..customize that label accordingly... And return that label..you are done.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"text"]; 
    return label;
}
```